# Translate PHP Document

Tags: php, api, translation

I have a large PHP Document in the following format:

```
<?php

define("TITLE","HAPPY DAYS");
define("FOOTER","This site is ok");
... 1000 more
?>
```

I want to translate it to Spanish.
I tried Google translate  but it also translated `TITLE` , `FOOTER` which are PHP keywords and should be not translated.

Any idea how to automate it?

If my call is

`API?text="TEXT HERE"`

it returns

`TEXT TRANSLATED`

Comment: Why not store the translations in the table and fetch according to the language chosen ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I didn't catch that , please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest two ways which i would prefer

**Method 1 :** ->Manually

You can have a table like this

```
S.No | Text      | French_Text  | Spanish_Text
   1 | KNowledge | Connaissance | Conocimiento
```

So You will give the english value by default, then if the user chooses the some language you can set a cookie or some storage locally,

And in the header page according to the selection you will refer the `French_Text` or `Spanish_Text`. You can have as many language like this.

Or you can go to any api

**Method 2  :** -> Using some api

You can select an api which allows to translate with respect to `div` or `class`. So that you can have translation for the particular area that you need.